# Taylor polynomials in Fourier Domain?

Tags: calculus, soft-question, fourier-analysis, taylor-expansion, approximation

Which types of functions admit Taylor polynomials in the Fourier domain?

Ok, this may sound cryptic. Therefore I will try to explain it more in depth.

We want to approximate function
$$x\to f(x) \text{ around } x_0 \to f(x_0)$$

We can look at normal Taylor polynomials first:

$$p_N(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{N}\frac{f^{(k)}(x_0)}{k!} (x-x_0)^k$$

Here all is fun and games and we see that we have well defined coefficients $$c_k=\frac{f^{(k)}(x_0)}{k!}$$
which probably are derived in your first Uni course on calculus.

But what if we instead use trigonometric polynomials?

$$p_N(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{N}a_k \sin(x-x_0)^k+ b_k\cos(x-x_0)^k$$

Can we derive which $a_k$, $b_k$ would do a best fit "close to" $x_0$?

Also, in what sense would this expansion be a "best fit" (for given number of terms $N+1$)?